# nested if conditionalConstruct in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Do you know If and how can I rewrite the code below in a better form for different values of m,k,l?

It is a nested if loop that I want to to check b for all m,k,l, but the code below is too big, I would like to simplify it. Can I?

```
 If[b > m,  If[(b - 1) > k, If[(b - 2) > l, b - 3, b - 2], 
 If[(b - 1) > l, b - 2, b - 1]],  If[b < m, 
 If[(b + 1) > k, If[(b + 2) < l, b + 3, b + 2],   If[(b + 1) < l, b + 2, b + 1]], 
 If[b > k, If[(b - 1) > l, b - 2, b - 1],   If[b < k, If[(b + 1) < l, b + 2, b + 1], 
 If[b > l, b - 1, If[b < l, b + 1, b]]]]]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that `If` is a conditional construct, not a loop.

Comment: @Sebastian Paaske Torholm Thank you very much, I posted it there as well

Comment: @Szabolcs yes yes, I know that I wrote loop by mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: are all variables integers? what's the range of values each variable can assume? what do you actually want to compute?

Comment: @Thies Heidecke Yes all the variables are integers. b is changing every timestep and acording to the above condition I want to give it a new value according to the values of m,l,k

Comment: @Thies Heidecke the range of variabloes are between 5-35

Comment: Can you tell us what this loop applies to and how you developed these conditions?

Comment: @eacousineau yes, I will edit my question to help you understand what I want to do.

Comment: This question can be answered by looking up the documentation for If, Which and Switch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Notice that you have `If` statements for both `b > m` and `b < m`, as well as `b > k` and `b < k`. These pairs can each be two halves of the one `If` statement.
2. Convert all the top level conditionals into a `Which` statement. Look up the documentation in Mathematica for more information.
3. You can probably also convert the relationships between `b` and `l` to simpler `Which` statements.

Comment: Thank you I will check out which statment. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that which is what I need here, also I used b>m and b<m because I wanted to check out b==m too.

Comment: which is not checking all my conditions, it is giving me back the result of the first contition tha is true, which is not what I want

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you replace the whole statement with a single Which statement. I was suggesting that you extract the conditionals that are mutually exclusive, eg b>m, b<m, b==m, and redo those bits as a Which statement. Note I said "top level" conditionals. I would suggest you work out what the tree structure of your conditions is and work out how to simplify the code using a combination of If and Which. I am about to board a plane and cannot help you any further.